# naming a boolean field

Tags: naming-conventions

I build an employee planning system for a medical environment. Normally the employees are busy with patient care. Sometimes an employee will be busy with non patient care and I like to model that situation in my database. My first thought was to add a field like

```
boolean noPatientCare default false
```

But then I remembered how I hate messages with a negation in them, like "Are you sure you don't want to save this file?" and wondered if it would be better to make it like this

```
boolean patientCare default true
```

How should I name my new column? Is there any theoretical background on this or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: This question is subjective, and not really possible to definitively answer. There are plenty of questions about naming conventions on [programmers.se], so I won't migrate it. If you find your question is not answered by any of the questions over there, please repost it on that site instead.

Comment: huh? From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." I had an actual and practical problem. User socha23 gave the answer that solved my problem!

Comment: It also states that open-ended questions should not be asked. What is wrong with "IsBusyWithPatientCare"? Or "IsAvailableForPatentCare"? There is no definite answer here, only "conventions". As such, if this question is "what is an appropriate naming convention for a boolean field", it should go on [programmers.se]. Either way, since you have gotten your answer, I question the value for future visitors, and then it would be closed as too-localized.

Comment: The answer to my question is a choice between "noPatientCare" and "patientCare". If that is considered as open-ended, the only valid questions will be questions having only one possible answer!

Comment: Isn't there a difference between an answer and a good answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find conditional and logical statements easier to read and understand if variables mean positive propositions, and not their negations. Consider:

```
if (patientCare || somethingOther) println("Employee is busy with patient care or something other)
```

versus

```
if (!noPatientCare || somethingOther) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Differentiate between boolean 0/1 (care/no care) and two-state A/B (patient care / nonpatient care).

Inherent negatives are bad. Naming conventions that suggest negative where there is none are worse. So definitely not `noPatientCare` because this would suggest occupied with patient care or unoccupied. Using `nonpatientCare` implies a different occupation.

Still, if this is a three-state `patientCare`/`nonpatientCare`/`unoccupied`(or other) then use enum, not bool and name the field for the generic property (careOccupation), not for one of the values. If it's a strictly two-state, there is no serious reason why it can't be "usually true" `boolean patientCare default true`.

Even then think twice before choosing bool over enum for this pick. Are you completely sure there won't be a new separate category, or that one of the categories won't be split into more narrow subcategories? It may be definitely worth picking a collective name for the field and descriptive value names than going with bool when the distinction between "true" and "false" is not apparent.

Example from my work: workMode==NIGHT_MODE or workMode==DAY_MODE, vs bool dayWorkMode. Coding special exceptions for night time operation with `if(!dayWorkMode)` would feel awkward as night time is not some lack of condition, just a different condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of taste and readability.

And you could find another word or concept. For instance, perhaps a medical worker not working with a patient could be said to work on administrative or miscellaneous tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd *generally* try to avoid negation in boolean variable names.

I've once written a good example of *violating* this rule with a method like this:

```
void frobnicate(boolean negate);
```

The argument was actually called `negate` and if you wanted to actually "negate" the `frobnicate` call you'd write `frobnicate(true)`. The "positive" `frobnicate` call would be `frobnicate(false)`. Reading this code afterwards was a formidable brain-twister. Avoid it, if you can.

I some cases, however, the jargon and/or environment might dictate a specific word and changing that to be in the non-negated form might actually make your code *harder* to understand.

Comment: You should have called the argument doNotNegate :)